# What is the structure or format of the logs generated by GlassFish Server? Is it configurable?

Tags: logging, glassfish, format

The glassfish server generates logs which can be error logs or debug logs or whatever, which is visible in the console. I wanted to know if it is configurable. Some knowledge about its log-format and what are the fields that it contains would also be helpful.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/abluk.html#gkmex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to the location of log files. It is found here:

"**C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log**"

But its still unclear about the formats. If anyone can just clarify the fields logged in it. And whether its configurable or not.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the access log is certainly configurable. Go to Configurations > server-config > HTTP Service and see the field **Format**. Values can be found here: [GF2 Access Log Patterns and Nicknames](https://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/access_log_patterns_and_nicknames)

(Though I would *love* to see some more detailed description...)

Comment: Aargh! Oracle has suddenly (re)moved that blog. But have a look here: [
Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 Domain File Format Reference ](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17811_01/html/820-7694/abhay.html#abhaz) !